# How to implement multithreading in wasm created using golang?

Tags: multithreading, go, webassembly

I am working on a javascript project which initially had all complex logic written in JS. However it was very slow so we had ported all the complex logic to golang now due to architectural constraints we cannot call APIs of the golang, so we moved towards wasm where you build your golang code into a wasm file and call it from your js code and hence eliminating API calls.

Now everything was working fine until we have received some complex object which takes a lot of time if you execute through wasm but takes only few seconds if you run it through golang. So my question is can I implement multithreading into wasm file loaded in browser?

Comment: Multi-threading is not yet officially supported in wasm: https://github.com/WebAssembly/proposals

Comment: Why do you think multithreading would help? If you run it in normal Go without threads, is it slow, too?

Comment: @Flimzy If I run in go it gives quick response but when I build wasm for the code and run in browser it takes too much time, almost 4x time. My thinking behind multithreading with wasm is that, I run same calculation for multiple object so If I make my golang code multithreaded and run that code using wasm then it will provide better output.

Comment: Yes, but does it run slowly in Go if you disable threading? I suspect it's just faster in Go because Go is faster.

Answer (score 2):

> So my question is can I implement multithreading into wasm file loaded in browser?

In a word: **No.**

Multithreading isn't officially supported in WASM at all yet. It's still [just a proposal](https://github.com/WebAssembly/proposals).  That said, there's already an [issue](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/28631) tracking this for Go/WASM.

So what this means, in practical terms, is that, optimistically, Go 1.14 is the first Go version likely to include (experimental) WASM Threading support, which will probably come out 2020Q1.  Stable support likely will take at least one more Go release cycle, so perhaps 2020Q3 you'll be able to use this in production.